# How to change the default Video folder from Ubuntu TV

Tags: ubuntu-tv

I installed Ubuntu TV but the default video folder it uses is the Videos folder but i have all my videos in a different folder. How can i change the folder to the folder where my videos are located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs` with an editor. One line looks like:

```
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Change the directory `Videos` to whatever you like and restart your session (log out and login again). Now your default Video-directory is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will test this later when i get home ...